# Example of how to simulate humanoid biped using ROS/Gazebo

Tags: simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a custom full-body humanoid biped using ROS/Gazebo.
Are there any examples of how to do this?
Is there a baseline humanoid example from which to build upon?

Thanks

TurtleBot_Fan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33755/example-of-how-to-simulate-humanoid-biped-using-ros/gazebo/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The two available humanoid models that come to my mind are the [Nao](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao_description) and [Romeo](http://ros.org/wiki/romeo_description) description. These currently offer no gazebo support. Simulating a full body humanoid is a challenging simulation task (at least when not cheating by artificially nailing the standing foot to the floor or using other hacks). As far as I´m aware, there is no solution for gazebo available at the moment, so you either have the option to try it out yourself or wait a little, as Gazebo will likely be significantly improved in this direction in the future for the [DARPA robotics challenge](http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/robotics-software/darpa-robotics-challenge-simulation-software-open-source-robotics-foundation).

Another related option would be to have a look at the [OpenHRP3](http://www.openrtp.jp/openhrp3/en/about.html) simulator, which works very well for humanoid robot simulation (but has no ROS interface). /edit: As described in the comment below, there is a ROS interface available.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-10**:
we have openhrp3 ros interface under rtm-ros-robotics repository, see http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics/wiki/ROS_English for more info. Any feedback, comment, request are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of 2020...

#### Maintained

- [ROBOTIS-OP3](http://wiki.ros.org/robotis_op3)
- [ROBOTIS-THORMANG3](http://wiki.ros.org/thormang3_mpc)

#### Unmaintained / Outdated

- [DRCSim (darpa robotics challenge by DARPA) which uses Atlas](https://github.com/osrf/drcsim)
- [SRCSim (space robotics challenge by NASA) which uses R5](https://github.com/osrf/srcsim)

It's a shame these useful resources are unmaintained...

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1